# Strategy - Scaling in and out multiples orders with specific conditions

Tags: pine-script

I'm struggling with pine script strategy logic. My script is based on MAs cross to get long & short (trend following system, only snippet for long below), with a main signal to get HTF_Long and another signal to get complementary(ies) LTF_Long :

```
strategy(title="Pyramiding and several entry orders", pyramiding=2,
     overlay=true, close_entries_rule="ANY")

IsFlat = (strategy.position_size == 0)
IsUptrend = MA5 > MA7
HTF_LongEntry = crossover(MA1,MA5) and IsFlat and IsUptrend
HTF_LongExit = crossunder(MA1,MA5) and IsUptrend
LTF_LongEntry = crossover(MA1,MA4) and strategy.position_size > 0 and IsUptrend
LTF_LongExit = crossunder(MA1,MA4) and IsUptrend

if (HTF_LongEntry)
    strategy.entry(id="HTF Entry", long=true)
if (LTF_LongEntry)
    strategy.entry(id="LTF Entry", long=true)
if (LTF_LongExit)
    strategy.exit(id="LTF Entry Exit", from_entry="LTF Entry",
         stop=LTFLongStopPrice)
if (HTF_LongExit)
    strategy.exit(id="HTF Entry Exit", from_entry="HTF Entry",
         stop=HTFLongStopPrice)
```

The rule is that only HTF_LongEntry can happen first (IsFlat), then, each time LTF_LongEntry/LTF_LongExit signals appear, a complementary long is opened and closed with a different size than HTF_LongEntry.

This LTF_LongEntry/LTF_LongExit can happen X times (how to manage pyramiding here?) while HTF_LongEntry is still active. Each LTF_LongEntry as to be closed by a LTF_LongExit and there can't be pyramiding with LTF_LongEntry (meaning that LTF_LongEntry has to be closed by LTF_LongExit before a new LTF_LongEntry).

As soon as HTF_LongEntry is not active anymore, LTF_LongEntry can't be generated anymore (so do LTF_LongExit). To finish, this logic is as well followed by the MAs lengths crossover/crossunder.

Both LTFLongStopPrice and HTFLongStopPrice are given by trailing logic and I'd like to find a way to exit both HTF & LTF either with stop order Trailing or market order if the exit condition is met first. Do I have to create two exit strategies for each?

My question is : 
What do I get wrong as my entries/exits order are not respected? Why is it the case as they are based on MA cross? Also, do I need to be careful about something when duplicating the working code for the short logic? (I can only be long (HTF+LTF) or short (HTF+LTF) at the same time)
[image]

Comment: In your screenshot I see the `HTF Entry` entry short position but in your script example there is no this entry. Could you make full flagged example and post screenshot with problem on it? But probably you long position are closed by short entry (position reverse) ...